# To use SELECT query in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I want to list rows from a table which relates to a where clause which need to compare list of records from two tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CONA.DOCUMENTID), CONA.CONTENTID 
FROM TABLEA AS CONA 
INNER JOIN TABLEB AS CTAGA ON CTAGA.CONTENTID = CONA.CONTENTID
WHERE CONA.DOCUMENTID LIKE 'PM%' 
AND (
  SELECT TAGID 
  FROM  TABLEB 
  WHERE CTAGA.CONTENTID = CONA.CONTENTID
) IN (SELECT TAGID FROM TABLEC)
```

In the above `SELECT TAGID FROM  TABLEB WHERE CTAGA.CONTENTID = CONA.CONTENTID` will have

abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno

and

`SELECT TAGID FROM TABLEC` will have abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu

Is it possible to check the all the records in list A is there in list B

Using the above I additionally the multiple values in the table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT (CONA.DOCUMENTID),TAGID FROM TABLEB As CTAGA
 Join TABLEC As CONA  On CTAGA.CONTENTID = CONA.CONTENTID
 Where CTGA.TAGID in (SELECT TAGID FROM TABLEC)
 AND CONA.DOCUMENTID LIKE 'PM%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CONA.DOCUMENTID), CONA.CONTENTID 
FROM TABLEA AS CONA INNER JOIN TABLEB AS CTAGA ON CTAGA.CONTENTID = CONA.CONTENTID 
                      AND CTAGA.TAGID IN (SELECT TAGID FROM TABLEC)                    
WHERE CONA.DOCUMENTID LIKE 'PM%'
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CONA.DOCUMENTID), CONA.CONTENTID 
FROM TABLEA AS CONA INNER JOIN TABLEB AS CTAGA ON CTAGA.CONTENTID = CONA.CONTENTID                                          
WHERE CONA.DOCUMENTID LIKE 'PM%' AND EXISTS (
                                             SELECT 1 
                                             FROM TABLEC
                                             WHERE CTAGA.TAGID = TABLEC.TAGID
                                             )
```